# How to get source id with HTML5 Drag&Drop

Tags: html

I'm dragging an image like it's done [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2).
I'm trying to get the id of the div, which I start the dragging process from.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you linked, the function `drag()` is triggered by the onDragStart event of the image node. This event object is passed to the `ev` argument of `drag()`, giving the `drag()` function access to the event's target -- that is, the element you're dragging -- via `ev.target`.

Since you have the target, you can access the target's parent node with `ev.target.parentNode`, and you can access the parent node's ID via `ev.target.parentNode.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me... adapted from the w3schools.com example.

Open the Javascript console to see console.log of id of dragged item, source and target.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .dropbox {
      width: 350px;
      height: 70px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  function addEventToClass(cls, fx, node = document, e = 'click') { 
     Array.from(node.querySelectorAll('.' + cls)).forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener(e, fx)); 
  }

  function clickEvent(ev) { console.log('clicked item:', ev.target.id); }
  function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); }

  function drag(ev) {
     var id = ev.target.id;
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("itemid", id);
     var source = id ? document.getElementById(ev.target.id).parentNode.id : '';
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("source", source);
  }

  function drop(ev, target) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     var item = ev.dataTransfer.getData("itemid");
     var source = ev.dataTransfer.getData("source");
     console.log('id of dragged item is:', item);
     console.log('id of source:', source);
     console.log('id of target:', target.id);
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(item));
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="div1" class='dropbox' ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="drag1" class='dragitem' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this)" width="336" height="69">Item 1</div>
  <div id="drag2" class='dragitem' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this)" width="336" height="69">Item 2</div>
  <div id="div2" class='dropbox' ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <script>
     addEventToClass('dragitem', clickEvent);
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```